# Qt Creator new tab not showing up when run

Tags: qt, tabs, qt-creator, designer

New to Qt. I'm using the Qt Creator. I'm working on an existing project. I'm trying to add a new tab in the Design. It shows up in design between two other tabs that are showing up, but when I run it the tab is gone. I made sure the .ui file was saved. How do I get this tab to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Try a build clean.  This will force Qt to redo the moc file for the ui.

Hope that helps.